# Is this factoring method an algorithm?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, diophantine-equations, factoring

$x-y=d$ and $xy=p\,$ gives $x^2-dx-p=0$, with the positive solution
$x=\frac{1}{2}\big(d+\sqrt{d^2+4p} \big)$. Consider $x,y,d,p\,$ as integers $>\!0$, where only $p$ is known, in order to factorize $p$. Starting with $d=\!0$ stepping up with $1$ until
$d^2+4p$ is a perfect square. Would this value of $d$ guaranty that $x|p$?

While testing hundreds of times I have found no exceptions.

---

It's not a great method, but with optimal coding it's okay for $x-y<100,000$.

Comment: As long as $x$ becomes an integer, yes this would work.  For very large $p$ this approach may have some drawbacks however...

Comment: If efficiency does not matter, this is a perfectly valid algorithm (if $p$ is odd, $d$ must be even , this is a very slight modification) . But I do not think that it will beat trial division.

Comment: (To prove that there is always a $d$ which makes the inner expression a perfect square, note that $d=p-1$ is always a solution.)

Comment: Are you sure the title matches your actual question?

Comment: Even if we also consider odd $d$ , $x$ is an integer as soon as $d^2+4p$ is a perfect square.

Comment: This looks a bit like Fermat's factorization method. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method

Comment: maybe you are interested in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4153532/is-222221-a-prime/4158893#4158893) where I mentioned this algorithm and discussed Fermat's method

Comment: In fact, $y$ is then also an integer, so $x\mid p$ is guaranteed.

Comment: @BarryCipra No, that's not Fermat's method. Using Fermat to factor $pq$, you have to check $(p+q)/2-\sqrt{p q}=1/2(\sqrt p -\sqrt q)^2$ numbers, using this method you have to check $p-q=(\sqrt p -\sqrt q)(\sqrt p+\sqrt q)$ numbers, this is an increase by the factor $2(\sqrt p+\sqrt q)/(\sqrt p-\sqrt q)$ When using Fermats method it sometime helps to try to factor $tpq$ instead of $pq$, for a small number $t$. For  OP's method this will never help but only increase the number of trials by the factor $t$.

Comment: @Peter I think you cannot compare the performance of OP's algorithm with trial division. OP's algorithm works if you can split a number into to factors with a small difference. trial division works if the number contains at least one small prime factor. is p1 and p2 are twin primes, OP's algorithm will be always fast, but trial division will not work for large $p_1$. Trial division will work fast on $p_1^{e_1}\cdot ...\cdot p_k^{e_k}$ for small $p_i$ but in most cases OP's algorithm will fail.

Comment: $(1)$ The algorithm is at least closely related to Fermat's factoring method, it works well, if there are two divisors with a small difference. There are refined versions of Fermat's method. in its simplest form it is basically the algorithm demonstrated here. $(2)$ I have mentioned that this algorithm cannot compete with trial division. (See my first comment). I did not claim that its efficiency is comparable with trial division.

Comment: @BarryCipra You are right. Even if it is not Fermat's method it is related to it

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in some comments, this method will work and as Barry Cipra mentioned this is related to Fermat's factoring method. It was first published in 1792 by C.F.Kausler. This and other historical facts I mention in this post can be found in Leonard Dickson's book ["History of the Theory of Numbers"](https://archive.org/details/historyoftheoryo01dick/page/356/mode/2up) in chapter 14,  "Methods of Factoring", page 357.

Fermat used that fact that a number that can be split in two factors can be represented as the difference of two squares. If $$n=pq$$ then $$n=a^2-b^2$$ if we select $a,b$ such that

$$q=a-b\\p=a+b$$
we then have
$$a=\frac{p+q}2 \\ b=\frac{p-q}2$$

So we have
$$a^2-n=b^2$$
and Fermat proposed to check the numbers $a$ where $$a \ge \lceil \sqrt n \rceil$$ until we have found one such that $a^2-n$ is a perfect square. So we have to check the integer numbers in the interval $[\sqrt{pq}, \frac{p+q}2].$

We also can write
$$b^2+n=a^2$$
and  Kausler and you  propose to check all $b\ge0$ until we have found onw such that $b^2-n$ is a perfect square. Her the integer numbers in the interval $[0, \frac{p-q}/2]$ have to be checked.
We have $$(p+q)/2-\sqrt{p q}=1/2(\sqrt p -\sqrt q)^2$$ and $$p-q=(\sqrt p -\sqrt q)(\sqrt p+\sqrt q)$$ and so
$$\frac{p-q}{(p+q)/2-\sqrt{p q}}=2\frac{\sqrt p+\sqrt q}{\sqrt p-\sqrt q} \tag 1$$
So the numbers to check is for your algorithm higher by the factor $(1)$ than the number of numbers that Fermat's algorithm has to check.
In a letter from about 1643 Fermat demonstrated his method bei factoring the number
$2027651281=44021\cdot 46061$. Using his method one has to check $11$ numbers, using your method onw has to check $1020$.
One can decrease the number that one has actually to check if one considers the residues of squares with respect to a modulus. For example Fermats number has the remainder $81$ modulo $100$.

$$81+b^2\pmod{100}$$ cannot be a square for $b^2\equiv 1\pmod {100}$ or  $b^2\equiv 6\pmod {100}$.